# Cutting and pasting row between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to cut a row and paste it if it has the word done in column S.

This is the best I've been able to manage, but it just deletes the row.

```vb
Sub TESTMACRO()
'
' TESTMACRO Macro
' CUT LINE PASTE AND SORT

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ACTIVE ROYS JOBS").Activate
   
Dim rngA As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rngA = Range("S1", Range("S65536").End(xlUp))
For Each cell In rngA
    If cell.Value = "DONE" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Cut

        Sheets("COMPLETED JOBS").Select
    
        Sheets("completed jobs").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Does your data in `ACTIVE ROYS JOBS` start in column `A`?

Comment: **1.** No need to loop. Use Autofilter as shown in  [How to copy a line in excel using a specific word and pasting to another excel sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s/11633207#11633207) **2.** Once you copy across the data, Simply Delete it from the original sheet :)

Comment: Other links worth reading **1.** [Finding Last Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) **2.** [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: thank you for the links, ill read them now.

Comment: yes it starts in column A through to column S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Siddharth Rout's (always) sound advice, the following code will copy - then delete - each row using `AutoFilter`.  Please let me know how you go with it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long, PasteRow As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACTIVE ROYS JOBS")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("COMPLETED JOBS")

PasteRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With ws1.Range("S1").CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter 19, "DONE"
        LRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Row
        If LRow = 1 Then
            MsgBox "No ""DONE"" records found"
            .AutoFilter
            Exit Sub
        End If
    .Offset(1).EntireRow.Copy ws2.Cells(PasteRow, 1)
    .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You are a superstar and officially my hero! It works beautifully

Comment: Thank you QUin.  Please mark the answer as 'accepted' (click on the big check mark) if it achieves what you want.